# how set one language by default in joomla

Tags: joomla

I use Joomla 1.5.24 Stable, to translate the site using JoomFish 2.2.3 released

In content Languages in joomfish language manager I have 3 language, en, ru and ro, by default is set ro, active is all.

How to set default display language for the site in joomla regardless of browser language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Go to administrtor -> Select Extensions → Language Manager from the
>   drop-down menu on the back-end of your Joomla! installation or click
>   the icon Language in the control center.

[image]

Comment: I set Romanian language by default <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zBqUH.jpg" width="100" height="100"> but if you access the site with a browser in the English language, the English language is loaded, but would be Romanian

Comment: Please check , if default language Romanian is settled default for admin or front site ? There are 2 options if for admin or front website.

Comment: And for Administrator default is Ro

Comment: But by default is set to Ro :-(

Comment: Try out these ,
Maybe it will help u..
http://www.joomfish.net/en/documentation/general-docs/195-faq
http://www.joomfish.net/en/documentation/tutorials/197-basic-configuration-after-installing-jf

Comment: I did these steps and now it works! THX for help :-)                      If a visitor enters your website, he/she sees the website in the language according to the browser settings

To change this, go the the JFrouter plugin, which is in extensions > plugin manager > system plugins. This plugin should be the first system plugin, so you can check that right away. If you open the plugin, you'll see the parameters.