# how to make chinese language a default page in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I have 2 different languages in the website, and would like to make the Chinese language as a default home page

how do i do that ?i am using Joomla 2.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427420/how-set-one-language-by-default-in-joomla Is this question relevant?

Comment: Also, see the search results [here](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=joomla+default+language&oq=joomla+default+language&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i22i30l5j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l2.762.4355.0.4506.24.23.0.0.0.0.401.2549.8j11j4-1.20.0.ehm_pq_qw%2Chmrde%3D0%2Chmffs%3D10%2Chmffl%3D3%2Chmffmp%3D0-9...0...1.1.47.hp..5.19.2136.0.hdW4nd9L1kA).

Answer (score 0):

I supose you already install chinese and setup it in the admin language manager. I think you need to create a new menu Home in Chinese and setup like default.
Anyways joomla all the time will show the page in the main language setup in the browser.
Another way: go to Language Admin and choose the chinese language like default.